# Trace the function implemented by DeviceioControl

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, windows-ce, device-driver

I am working with a WinCE device which has a radio manager driver written for it in MFC. In the code for the Radio GUI, I can see the function Deviceiocontrol with a specific IOCTL being called. However, I'm unable to trace the particular piece of code called by this function. Can someone tell me how Deviceiocontrol works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DeviceIoControl calls through to the device driver by using the file handle. You have to use a kernel debugger if you want to step into the device driver itself.

The file handle represents a kernel object which consists of a DEVICE_OBJECT structure which contains a function table. In this table at the index of IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL, the driver sets its handle function. The function then gets called with the io control parameters which are packaged into an IRP.

Comment: Thankyou! I'm afraid I don't know how to use a kernel debugger. I can see the code for the Radio Manager and I believe the function RadioManager_IOControl(Rmgr * context,IOCTL_...,BYTE *pInBuffer, DWORD inSize,BYTE *pOutBuffer, DWORD outSize, DWORD *pOutSize) (in the radio driver) is what is called by deviceiocontrol. My problem is that deviceiocontrol has a handle to Rmgr in its argumentlist while RadioManager_IOControl of the device driver has a pointer to a Rmgr structure in its argument list. I am unable to trace how this structure is populated.

Comment: The `Rmgr*` is the device handle you pass to `DeviceIoControl`. This handle is populated when you call `CreateFile`. The exact way of its population is driver/implementation specific. It might be populated every time your driver's XXX_Open is called and it might be populated during the XXX_Init of the driver and it might be just a dummy handle that the driver returns. Driver specific.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the source code for the driver the IOCTL is sent to?
You pass a handle to `DeviceIoControl` - the handle is opened using a call to `CreateFile(L"XXX#:",...)` - XXX being the prefix of the driver as set in the registry. and # is the index the driver is giving at load time (also can be set in the registry).
To see the functionality that is performed, search for the IOCTL you send to `DeviceIoControl` in the driver's source code. You will find it in the driver's implementation of `XXX_IoControl`.